# ADD Specific values in SQL Column determined by other Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Database that determines different values based on a label.
Where the label determines whether it's an exempted value or not.
For instance, 2 = non exempted and 3 = exempted. If I run a query my results look something like this

```
    |Name  |ExemptionStatus |Total Value|
    |X     |2               |100        |  
    |X     |3               |200        |
```

My Query is

```
    SELECT NAME, EXEMPTIONSTATUS
           SUM(TOTAL_VALUE) AS 'TOTAL VALUE'
    FROM ORDER_ACCOUNT JOIN ACCOUNT_INVOICE
    WHERE ORDER_ACCOUNT.DATE BETWEEN 'M/D/YEAR' AND 'M/D/YEAR'
    GROUP BY NAME, EXEMPTIONSTATUS
    ORDER BY NAME ASC
```

How can I get my query to create a new column for the values, for example:

```
    |Name  |NON EXEMPT VALUE|EXEMPT VALUE|
    |X     |100             |200         |
```

I just don't know how how I would sort it whether it's in my Where clause or not.

Comment: Why don't you use a Pivot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a CASE statement within a SUM to only total NON EXEMPT, then EXEMPT, and select them as separate columns.  Similar to the following (might need to add TOTAL_VALUE to the GROUP BY, or remove EXEMPTIONSTATUS)

```
SELECT
NAME
,SUM(CASE WHEN EXEMPTIONSTATUS = 2 THEN TOTAL_VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS 'NON EXEMPT VALUE'
,SUM(CASE WHEN EXEMPTIONSTATUS = 3 THEN TOTAL_VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS 'EXEMPT VALUE'
FROM ORDER_ACCOUNT JOIN ACCOUNT_INVOICE
WHERE ORDER_ACCOUNT.DATE BETWEEN 'M/D/YEAR' AND 'M/D/YEAR'
GROUP BY NAME, EXEMPTIONSTATUS
ORDER BY NAME ASC
```

EDIT: New code below adds new columns to your existing table.  you will need to replace the `#Test` with your tables, but I believe this will get you what you're looking for.

```
SELECT
NAME,
EXEMPTIONSTATUS
,[TOTAL_VALUE]
,(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN EXEMPTIONSTATUS = 2 THEN TOTAL_VALUE ELSE 0 END) FROM #Test t WHERE t.NAME = NAME) 'NON EXEMPT VALUE'
,(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN EXEMPTIONSTATUS = 3 THEN TOTAL_VALUE ELSE 0 END) FROM #Test t WHERE t.NAME = NAME) 'EXEMPT VALUE'
FROM #Test
```

This gives me the following output

```
| NAME | EXEMPTIONSTATUS | TOTAL_VALUE | NON EXEMPT VALUE  | EXEMPT VALUE  |
| X    | 2               | 100         | 100               | 200           |
| X    | 3               | 200         | 100               | 200           |
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. It does though put Zero In place of the values that should be there in the column, so I just need to see if something like where  NOT EXEMPT VALUE LIKE '0' or something. But at least this got me on the right track.

Comment: Hmm, that shouldn't be replacing anything with a 0...what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I apologize I'm sort of new at this I didn't notice it correctly. Where it state's "ELSE 0" in the CASE, The 0 values show up. I just want to figure out how to align the new columns together.

Comment: So they line up for you like in my example? For me, maybe I can clarify to make sure we're on the same page. Instead of creating 1 Row for X and having both new columns, it will create the new column, but not eliminate the row. So I have the values in separate columns, but some rows have not been eliminated. Where the new separated value should be, There's a 0, if I remove the ELSE clause it's NULL.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying...edit to my answer to come

Comment: I'm an idiot, I'm still grouping by EXEMPT_STATUS so it's still showing up, that's why, if I remove that from my Group By Clause, it works. Thanks again for your help.!

Comment: @eldiablo1121 This resultset still has two two rows rather than one which was the way the question was asked.

Comment: yes that is correct, but it was because of my group clause, it's all right for now.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your table structure is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(ID int, Name nvarchar(20), ExemptionStatus int, TotalValue int);
INSERT INTO tab(ID, Name, ExemptionStatus, TotalValue) values (1, 'X', 2, 100);
INSERT INTO tab(ID, Name, ExemptionStatus, TotalValue) values (2, 'X', 3, 200);
```

So your data looks like this:

```
   ID   Name   ExemptionStatus   TotalValue
    1     X        2                100
    2     X        3                200
```

Then the query you'd use is:

```
SELECT      NotExempted.Name,
            NotExempted.NonExemptValue,
            Exempted.ExemptValue
FROM        (SELECT     Name,
                        CASE 
                            WHEN ExemptionStatus = 2 THEN TotalValue
                        END
                        AS 'NonExemptValue'
             FROM       #tab
            ) NotExempted
INNER JOIN  (SELECT     Name,
                        CASE 
                            WHEN ExemptionStatus = 3 THEN TotalValue
                        END
                        AS 'ExemptValue'
             FROM       #tab
            ) Exempted ON NotExempted.Name = Exempted.Name
WHERE        NotExempted.NonExemptValue IS NOT NULL
AND          Exempted.ExemptValue IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY     NotExempted.Name,
             NotExempted.NonExemptValue,
             Exempted.ExemptValue
```

You result will look like this :

```
Name  NonExemptValue    ExemptValue
 X         100             200
```

You can see this here -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8902d3/2

Now, let's say you have data like this :

```
CREATE TABLE #tab(ID int, Name nvarchar(20), ExemptionStatus int, TotalValue int)
INSERT INTO #tab(ID, Name, ExemptionStatus, TotalValue) values (1, 'X', 2, 100)
INSERT INTO #tab(ID, Name, ExemptionStatus, TotalValue) values (2, 'X', 3, 200)
INSERT INTO #tab(ID, Name, ExemptionStatus, TotalValue) values (3, 'X', 2, 1000)
INSERT INTO #tab(ID, Name, ExemptionStatus, TotalValue) values (4, 'X', 3, 2000)
INSERT INTO #tab(ID, Name, ExemptionStatus, TotalValue) values (5, 'X', 2, 1045)
INSERT INTO #tab(ID, Name, ExemptionStatus, TotalValue) values (6, 'X', 3, 2045)
INSERT INTO #tab(ID, Name, ExemptionStatus, TotalValue) values (7, 'X', 2, 1034)
INSERT INTO #tab(ID, Name, ExemptionStatus, TotalValue) values (8, 'X', 3, 2023)
INSERT INTO #tab(ID, Name, ExemptionStatus, TotalValue) values (9, 'X', 2, 1023)
INSERT INTO #tab(ID, Name, ExemptionStatus, TotalValue) values (10, 'X', 3, 2076)
```

which looks like this:

```
   ID   Name   ExemptionStatus   TotalValue
   1      X          2              100
   2      X          3              200
   3      X          2             1000
   4      X          3             2000
   5      X          2             1045
   6      X          3             2045
   7      X          2             1034
   8      X          3             2023
   9      X          2             1023
  10      X          3             2076
```

If you need to sum the total value up, then you can use the following query (which is a slight modification of the query above):

```
SELECT      NotExempted.Name,
            NotExempted.NonExemptValue,
            Exempted.ExemptValue
FROM        (SELECT     Name,
                        CASE 
                            WHEN ExemptionStatus = 2 THEN (SELECT SUM(TotalValue) FROM #tab WHERE ExemptionStatus = 2)
                        END
                        AS 'NonExemptValue'
             FROM       #tab
            ) NotExempted
INNER JOIN  (SELECT     Name,
                        CASE 
                            WHEN ExemptionStatus = 3 THEN (SELECT SUM(TotalValue) FROM #tab WHERE ExemptionStatus = 3)
                        END
                        AS 'ExemptValue'
             FROM       #tab
            ) Exempted ON NotExempted.Name = Exempted.Name
WHERE        NotExempted.NonExemptValue IS NOT NULL
AND          Exempted.ExemptValue IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY     NotExempted.Name,
             NotExempted.NonExemptValue,
             Exempted.ExemptValue
```

Your result will look like this :

```
Name  NonExemptValue    ExemptValue
 X         4202             8344
```

You can see this here -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02c76/3

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: I got it to work, but now what I want to learn is how to do the addition of two columns that were created from the case. I'm going to try to figure it out, if not I'll post it as a new question since that's proper etiquette.

Comment: Actually I got what I needed, the sum of the other two values are initially done when I don't select the case, I got it.

Comment: @d_li1121 I have added a fiddle to show the result set more clearly. **You can see that only one row is returned.**

Comment: @d_li1121 I've edited my answer to show you how to get the sum of the total value column.